# Remove part of URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have head to move a shop over from Zen cart to Wordpress Woocommerce but the companies site has  been optimised for SEO and is listed well and they already have links throughout google.

The original site had the following url structure

www.mysite.co.uk/{category-name}  &  www.mysite.co.uk/{category-name}/{product-name}

the wordpress/woocommerce url looks like this

www.mysite.co.uk/product-category/{category-name}  &

www.mysite.co.uk/product/{category-name}/{product-name}

I need to remove 'product-category' and 'product'.

at the moment I do not care how convoluted the solution is and it does not need to maintain this structure for future added categories only for categories already listed on google.

I do hope this makes seance and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to use RewriteRule in .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product-category/(.+) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product/(.+) $1
```

Smth like that, have not tested through, but I hope you got an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why not making 301 redirects to the new links?
It would keep the url value and position I think..